# How to return the selected dropdown value from custom component to main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a custom MUI select component in react and have used the same component multiple times in another component as below

**triggerDropDown.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';
import CheckCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleOutline';
import ArrowCircleUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowCircleUp';
import ArrowCircleDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowCircleDown';
import { useLocation  } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function TriggerDropDown({ inputLabelId, dropdownId, dropdownValue1, dropdownLabel }) {
    const [dropdownValue, setDropDownValue] = React.useState('');
    const location = useLocation();

    const handleChange = (event) => { 
        setDropDownValue(event.target.value);  
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setDropDownValue(dropdownValue1);
      }, [location, dropdownValue1])

    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 220 }}>
            <InputLabel id={inputLabelId}>{dropdownLabel}</InputLabel>
            <Select id={dropdownId} value={dropdownValue} label={dropdownLabel} onChange={handleChange}>
                <MenuItem value={-1}><Chip size="medium" icon={<ArrowCircleDownIcon />} label="Decreasing" color="error" /></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={0}><Chip size="medium" icon={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon />} label="No Trend" color="primary" /></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={1}><Chip size="medium" icon={<ArrowCircleUpIcon />} label="Increasing" color="success" /></MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    );
}
```

And I am calling the above component from another component multiple times by passing different values for labelId, dropdownID, etc.,

**MainComponent.js**

```
import TriggerDropDown from '../components/triggerDropDown.js';

<TriggerDropDown inputLabelId="Lbl_Id1" dropdownId="Id1" dropdownValue1={firstSelect} dropdownLabel="First" />
<TriggerDropDown inputLabelId="Lbl_Id2" dropdownId="Id2" dropdownValue1={secondSelect} dropdownLabel="Second" />
```

So whenever I try to get the values of **firstSelect** && **secondSelect** even after changing the values of dropdown, it is not getting affected.

Can someone help me on how to get the values for each of the dropdown in the MainComponent.js

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react there is a concept present is called lifting up the state

This is nothing but maintaining the state in the parent level and sending the state and callback as a parameter to child

Now in you case:
You are sending the state to child. but not sent the callback (setfirstSelect or
setsecondSelect) in order to update the value.

In triggerdropdown.js file
you are having a state internally (dropdownvalue). And you are just updating the state which will never affect the parent.
My suggestion
create a seperate useState for each triggerdropdown component in parent level (maincomponent.js) and send the value and callback to the child component.
At child component you have to update the state

code snippet:
MainComponent.js

```
    import TriggerDropDown from '../components/triggerDropDown.js';
    const [firstSelect,setFirstselect]=useState();
    const [secondSelect,setSecondselect]=useState()
<TriggerDropDown inputLabelId="Lbl_Id1" dropdownId="Id1" dropdownValue1={firstSelect} setState={setFirstselect} dropdownLabel="First" />
    <TriggerDropDown inputLabelId="Lbl_Id2" dropdownId="Id2" dropdownValue1={secondSelect} setState={setSecondselect} dropdownLabel="Second" />
```

in TriggerDropdown.js

```
export default function TriggerDropDown({ inputLabelId, dropdownId, dropdownValue1, dropdownLabel, setState }) {
    const [dropdownValue, setDropDownValue] = React.useState('');
    const location = useLocation();

    const handleChange = (event) => { 
        setDropDownValue(event.target.value); 
        setState(event.target.value) 
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setDropDownValue(dropdownValue1);
      }, [location, dropdownValue1])

    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 220 }}>
            <InputLabel id={inputLabelId}>{dropdownLabel}</InputLabel>
            <Select id={dropdownId} value={dropdownValue} label={dropdownLabel} onChange={handleChange}>
                <MenuItem value={-1}><Chip size="medium" icon={<ArrowCircleDownIcon />} label="Decreasing" color="error" /></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={0}><Chip size="medium" icon={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon />} label="No Trend" color="primary" /></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={1}><Chip size="medium" icon={<ArrowCircleUpIcon />} label="Increasing" color="success" /></MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    );
}
```

hope this helps